# What does 'c' parameter do in coding?

Tags: c

What does parameter do in programming ?

For example

void main()

int n = 6;

int test(int n)

Is the int n inside the int test refer to the void main int 6 ? 
Can anyone explain further for me.

Tq guys have better understanding now.

Comment: It is used to send values to other functions.! for calculation or operation.

Comment: Hi, other than send,can it receive value from other functions for calculation or operation ?

Comment: you can receive updated value by returning the value from function using 'return' statement.

Comment: Which `c` parameter?

Comment: c programming..

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description..
n = 6 both in the main function and the test function.

E.g.

```
void main()
{
   int n = 6;
   test(n); //shows 8
   print("%d", n); //shows 6
}
int test(int n)
{
   n = n + 2;
   return n;
}
```

Here we have two 'n' in two functions representing two different values.

Answer (score -2):

If that function is inside main then "int test(int n)" is declaration of function and u need to write that function outside main.When u call test function u just pass value and no declaration of variable is required.For example test(n) will refer the n in the main program.